# org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound when testing through MockMvc

Tags: spring-mvc, mockmvc

I have defined a rest service using Spring Mvc 4 and then testing the same through MockMvc. Correct response is returned when I run the service using Tomcat 7 through following URL:

http://localhost:8080/SpringServiceSample/service/greeting/Niharika

But when I run the Junit Test, I get 404 error with following in my logs:

```
INFO: FrameworkServlet '': initialization completed in 159 ms
May 18, 2015 12:36:02 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/service/greeting] in DispatcherServlet with name ''
```

Following is the code:

**SpringServiceController.java**

```
package com.test.springservice.controller;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/service/greeting")
public class SpringServiceController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/{firstName}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public String getGreeting(
        @PathVariable String firstName) {
        String result = "Hello " + firstName;
        return result;
    }
}
```

**test-servlet.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd">
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.test.springservice.controller" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
</beans>
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>SpringServiceSample</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>


<servlet>
    <servlet-name>test</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>test</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**SpringServiceControllerTest.java**

```
package com.test.springservice.controller;

import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultHandlers.print;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.springframework.test.context.web.WebAppConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers;
import org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration
@WebAppConfiguration
public class SpringServiceControllerTest {
    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext ctx;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        this.mockMvc = webAppContextSetup(ctx).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetGreeting() throws Exception {
        String firstName = "Niharika";
        mockMvc.perform(
            MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/service/greeting").param(
                    "firstName", firstName))
            .andDo(print())
            .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk())
            .andExpect(
                    MockMvcResultMatchers.content().string(
                            "Hello " + firstName));
    }

    @Configuration
    public static class TestConfiguration {
        @Bean
        public SpringServiceController springServiceController() {
            return new SpringServiceController();
        }
    }
}
```

Please suggest what I may be doing wrong here.

Comment: I have the similar problem , and my error is :[org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound:1136] No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/xhr/ipopt/get] in DispatcherServlet with name ''. But I can access this url correctly in browser

Answer (score 0):

try add the `test-servlet.xml` to the `@ContextConfiguration` annotation, that is

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations={"classpath*:test-servlet.xml"})
@WebAppConfiguration
public class SpringServiceControllerTest {
    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext ctx;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;
```

By the way, add `<mvc:default-servlet-handler />` in `test-servlet.xml`